# Floor to another decimal precision

Tags: c#, algorithm, numbers

I apologize if this sounds easy but it's right on my blind spot

How do I convert a number like "0.4921" to the lower bound of another number, i.e.

- 0.4921 with 0.005 precision to be 0.490
- 0.4921 with 0.05 precision to be 0.45
- 0.4921 with 0.1 precision to be 0.40

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you are after, is an integer multiple of the precision.

Thus divide the number by the precision, floor, ceil or round it; then multiply back with the precision.

```
return Math.Floor(number / precision) * precision;
```